# A method inside async bock is not being called

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

My code is like below, I am trying ot call a cpu intensive method inside an async block, but that method is not being always called, sometimes it's called, sometimes not.

```
-(IBAction) aMethod
//some code

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        NSArray *allFiles = [appDel getAllFiles];
        totalFilesCount = [allFiles count];
    });
//some code
}
```

`backgroundQueue` is an instance variable declared in the interface file and created in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
 backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.backgroundprocessing", NULL);
```

The method `getAllFiles` is sometimes called and sometimes not (checked with breakpoints), the reason I am calling it into a dispatch_async block is that it took a lot of time to return the result. What seems to be wrong with my approach, should it be called in the main thread although it's cpu intensive method?

Comment: Can you update your code with how you create backgroundQueue

Comment: I don't see why it should not be called, but if backgroundQueue is a serial queue, it would not be called before a previous call has finished.

Comment: @sbarow, I just edited my post, `backgroundQueue` is basically an instance variable, I didn't declare it as property.

Comment: @Malloc: `dispatch_queue_create(..., NULL)` creates a serial queue.

Comment: @MartinR ah I see, so what type should be ? can you elaborate in an answer? thanx

Comment: Do you really want a concurrent queue? Does it make sense to start another `[appDel getAllFiles]` operation if one is still running?

Comment: but if I get the return object from `getAllFiles`, this means that the operation is done, so it seems to be safe to start another call, isn't ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35691/discussion-between-martin-r-and-malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create(..., NULL);
```

creates a *serial* queue, and not a concurrent queue as you assumed.
Therefore the block dispatched with

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{ ... });
```

is executed when all previous blocks dispatched to that queue have finished.
So if the first invocation is still running, it may look as if the second block
is not executed at all.

To create a concurrent queue, you would use

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create(..., DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

But you should check if it makes sense in your case to start another 
(long running) `[appDel getAllFiles]` operation if the previous operation is still
running.

A possible alternative would be to start another `[appDel getAllFiles]` operation only
if the previous one has already finished, and to do nothing if the previous operation
is still running. That can be done e.g. with an `NSOperationQueue`:

```
if ([opQueue operationCount] == 0) {
    [opQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSArray *allFiles = [appDel getAllFiles];
        totalFilesCount = [allFiles count];
    }];
}
```